# How to disable a submit button that is under a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following submit button on all my asp.net web application, to create or edit records:-

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

But I need to write a jQuery to disable the button once the user click on it (to avoid successive API calls to an external system,). So I wrote this code, but the button will not be disabled once clicked on.

```
  $(".btn btn-primary").click(function () {
            $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("input[type=submit]").css("background-color", "grey");
        });
```

Second question which approach I should follow, incase I need to re-enable the button again incase a model state error occur , after click on the submit button. can anyone advice please

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".btn.btn-primary").click(function () {
    $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("input[type=submit]").css("background-color", "grey");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: this will cover my first requirement of disabling the submit button once click on it . but what if the user clicks on the submit button, and then a client side validation error occurred (for example missing required field) , then in this way the button will stay disabled , even if the user correct the client side validation error...

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong

```
$(".btn.btn-primary").click(function () {
    $(this).prop("disabled", "disabled").css("background-color", "grey");
});
```

---

[this](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

Comment: but what if the user clicks on the submit button, and then a client side validation error occurred (for example missing required field) , in this case the button will stay disabled , even if the user correct the client side validation error... can you advice please

Comment: @JohnJohn Are you using jQuery Validation ?

Comment: @JohnJohn in your jQuery Validator `submitHandler: function(form) {
   $(".btn.btn-primary").prop("disabled", "disabled").css("background-color", "grey");
  }`

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
$(".btn btn-primary").click(function () {
            $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("input[type=submit]").css("background-color", "grey");
        });
```

for

```
    $(".btn .btn-primary").click(function (e) {

                $(this).attr({disabled:true});
                $("input[type=submit]").css("background-color", "grey");
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".btn.btn-primary").click(function () {
  $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $(".btn.btn-primary").click(function () {
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled")
               .css("background-color", "grey");
        e.preventDefault();

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To re-enable at a later stage use

```
$("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: but how I can define that in case the form return error (client side) after the user click on the submit button, to re-enable the button again ?

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above take into account whether or not the form submission was successful. What if the user forgot to complete a required a field? She would receive an error message, attempt to correct the error and then discover that she can not resubmit the form. Even if you solve that issue, once the user refreshes the page she can submit again.

What is the purpose of the form? If for example it is a registration form, I would simply fire an Ajax method once the email address has been entered which checks for the email address in the database and prevents the user from attempting to register the same email address twice. If on the other hand you are doing a survey and you wish to discourage multiple submissions from the same user I would create a cookie. On DOM ready your script would look for the cookie. If the cookie is present do not display the form.

Comment: the purpose of the form is to create new assets and edit existing assets, and some forms have around 25 fields . and you are right none of the answers above take into account whether or not the form submission was successful or if a client side validation error occurred. this was my main concern ..

Comment: @john john - You can definitely use the technique of disabling the submit. I would just incorporate some of the ideas I mentioned in the form handler so that you do so only after you've determined the that it's the correct course of action.

Comment: Have your form submit trigger JS validation. If required fields are incomplete show an error, don't submit the form. If there's no errors submit the form via Ajax. Your form handler can use jQuery deferred callbacks like .done() .fail() and .always(). Your .done() method, which is triggered by HTTP 200 response (success) can disable the form. I would do this by hiding the form. You could also do $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); If you want to make that "stick" after page refresh set a cookie. On DOM ready check for the cookie and disable the form if cookie is detected.

Comment: Alternatively, have your frontend validation call an Ajax method that checks if the user has already submitted this form by doing a database lookup. If the user has already submitted it disable the form. That's better than the cookie method since cookies can be deleted. Of course the cookie solution is easier to implement. Start by breaking it down into validateForm(), handleFormSubmit(), and disableForm(). If you go with the cookie option you could do setCookie() and getCookie() methods as well. There's a popular validation plugin for jquery and a jquery cookie plugin, too. HTH -- Neil